# VS 2022 17.5.1 Project contains a reference to a project which is unloaded

Tags: database, reference, visual-studio-2022, tsqlt

I have upgraded from VS 2019 Community Edition to VS Community 2022 17.5.1. When trying to build the project, the system complains with various errors. These errors seem related to database references as they are appearing with a yellow icon.

When I attempt to remove the database references and readd them, I get the following error message even though the corresponding project is loaded.

"Project xyz contains a reference to a project which is unloaded".

This issue was not occurring with previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

For those that find themselves with this issue. I had to resolve it by copying the master.dacpac file from the 2019 VS community file path and replace the master.dacpac in the 2022 file path.

There was also an update in VS Community 17.6.0 Preview 2.0 which solved some issues with SSDT.